# Knockout JS click binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am noew to Knockout JS and I am practicing the same at their website

[Knockout Practice Home](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=intro.)

So , the issue I am facing is I am not able to get the click binding working.

Here is my code sample

**View - HTML**

```
<ul data-bind="foreach:friends">
    <li>
        <strong data-bind="text: friendName"></strong>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: knowJS" />
        <input data-bind="value: favLib,visible: knowJS" />
    </li>
</ul>

<button data-bind="click: addFriend">Add Friend</button>
```

**ViewModel - JavaScript**

```
//Create a sample JS Class
function friend(name) {
    this.friendName = name;
    this.knowJS = ko.observable(false);
    this.favLib = ko.observable('');
};

// This is a simple *viewmodel* - JavaScript that defines the data and behavior of your UI
var AppViewModel= function(){
    this.friends = ko.observableArray([new friend("Chiranjib"), new friend("Nandy")]);
};

AppViewModel.addFriend= function(){
    this.friends.push(new friend("A new friend"));
};

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

This addFriend click event is not being fired. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `addFriend` function is in the wrong place, so KO can't find it. You've put it on the `AppViewModel` function itself, but where you want it is on objects *created by* that function.

Your browser is telling you about the problem, in fact. If you open your web console, you'll see:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "click: function (){return addFriend }"
Message: addFriend is not defined
```

Two ways to put it on the object instead: Put it on the object that will be the prototype of those objects (accessible via `AppViewModel.prototype`), or create it within the constructor function as you are with `friends`. I don't see any reason it can't be shared, so I'd go for the prototype:

```
AppViewModel.prototype.addFriend= function(){
// Note ----^^^^^^^^^^^
    this.friends.push(new friend("A new friend"));
};
```

Live example with that one change:

```js
//Create a sample JS Class
function friend(name) {
    this.friendName = name;
    this.knowJS = ko.observable(false);
    this.favLib = ko.observable('');
};

// This is a simple *viewmodel* - JavaScript that defines the data and behavior of your UI
var AppViewModel= function(){
    this.friends = ko.observableArray([new friend("Chiranjib"), new friend("Nandy")]);
};

AppViewModel.prototype.addFriend= function(){
    this.friends.push(new friend("A new friend"));
};

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

```html
<ul data-bind="foreach:friends">
    <li>
        <strong data-bind="text: friendName"></strong>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: knowJS" />
        <input data-bind="value: favLib,visible: knowJS" />
    </li>
</ul>

<button data-bind="click: addFriend">Add Friend</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

---

Side note: In JavaScript, the overwhelming convention is that constructor functions are initially capitalized like your `AppViewModel` is. So the `friend` function should be `Friend`.

Comment: You are the "Teacher" or the "Master". Happy Teacher's Day Sir :)